# Byte Array returns OutOfMemory Exception frequently in the app

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have a problem that I am facing `OutOfMemory Exception` frequently after 20 times when that Java file executed, statement responsible for the same is
`byte[] fileData = new byte[2097152]`.

Actually I have to allocate that much memory at the runtime with byte array but sometimes heap size increases and Memory unable to be freed for more objects for allocation that time OutOfMemory Exception is occurred. I searched for the same on web enough but I unable to get any successful solution. Please suggest me for the right solution about this problem.

**Error Stack:**

```
01-19 16:52:54.437: E/Cursor(5672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-19 16:52:54.437: E/Cursor(5672):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 16:52:54.577: I/System.out(5672): 1Record inserted
01-19 16:52:54.878: D/dalvikvm(5672): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1323 objects / 1091256 bytes in 35ms
```

Comment: Why do you allocate so big size of memmory, is this buffer for some big media file?

Comment: Yes, actually I have to get that amount of data from a video file, that's why I am using the same. It is mandatory.

Comment: Isn't there really another way of looking at this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to store the content of the video file in memory?  If you're reading it from a network connection, you can store it in a temporary file, e.g. on SD card, and then reference from there.  If you just want to display it in video player, you can play directly from the stream.  The main issue is that many android devices only have 16 MB of heap memory per process.  If you run this execution 20 times, you're allocating 40 MB, easily running out of memory.  You can try forcing garbage collection with `System.gc()` - but ultimately you have to re-think you app logic.

Comment: Actually my video is already in SD Card. Is there any other to solve this problem such as Reading chunk of data?